# YUM lock while running multiple Docker containers on a single host

Tags: cluster-computing, docker, puppet, yum

I am trying to deploy a cluster of multiple docker containers using puppet . when puppet is trying to install services , one of the containers see that there is a YUM lock and throws as error .Which is the best way to resolve this.

Comment: hmm it could be that one of your 'base' images hasn't finished performing a yum install. Can you provide more details?

Comment: also check if `yumhelper.py` is hanging. it is supplied by puppet and have ran into issues with it when there are network issues connecting to repo's. Not that it is the same issue as yours, but still might as well check.

Answer (score 0):

> Kill the yum process to unblock
>
> pidof -x yum | awk '{print $1}'
>
> It returns a pid.
>
> kill -9 (pid).
>
> Your yum is unlocked now and you proceed with installing the packages you need